# Django-filter 'icontains' isn't passing to my URL

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm using the 3rd-party Django-filter to make a search bar for my blog posts.

```py
import django_filters
from .models import Post
from django.db import models


class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    title = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='title')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = {
            'title': ['icontains'],
            }
    #I've tried using filter_overrides to no success
        filter_overrides = {
            models.CharField: {
                'filter_class': django_filters.CharFilter,
                'extra': lambda f: {
                    'lookup_expr': 'icontains',
                    },
                }
            }
```

I read that CharFilter and TextFilter default to exact however i thought i was changing that below. I've tried contains and icontains.
The search is passing to the url such as: "...blog/?title=foo". I've manually typed the ".../blog/?title__icontains=foo" url and this works, however the working url is not the url is that is being passed once i click my search button.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

*edit: to be clear, the filter is working but it is working as though it is 'exact' and not 'contains'. it will find results but only if i search for the full title

Answer (score 0):

Harry,

Have you tried the override defined by django-filter?

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = {
        'name': ['exact'],
        'release_date': ['isnull'],
    }
    filter_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {
            'filter_class': django_filters.CharFilter,
            'extra': lambda f: {
                'lookup_expr': 'icontains',
            },
        },
        models.BooleanField: {
            'filter_class': django_filters.BooleanFilter,
            'extra': lambda f: {
                'widget': forms.CheckboxInput,
            },
        },
    }
```

Comment: I don't think i fully understand how i'm meant to do this but i tried implementing what you said by adding: ```filter_overrides = {
            django_filters.CharFilter: {
                'filter_class': django_filters.CharFilter,
                'extra': lambda f: {
                    'lookup_expr': 'icontains',
                    },
                }
        }``` inside my filter, after the code in the main question. sadly this didn't fix the problem though.

Comment: @HarryWhitnear Refer to https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#overriding-default-filters and see if it helps you